# Do the nasal cilia move the particles trapped in the mucus out of the nose or down the throat?

Tags: anatomy, respiration, nose, cilia

Do the nasal cilia move the particles trapped in the mucus out of the nose or down the throat?
What is the direction of the pulse of the cilia? Is this changeable?

[image]

Comment: Mucus generally moves down the esophagus. If you notice , you will make many small swallow actions during the day, generally not enough volume to notice . It includes some saliva. As a result of cancer ,I cannot swallow so I am very aware of the mucus flow.

Answer (score 1):

The movement is towards the pharynx (to be then swallowed).

It's useful, in the case of respiratory cilia, not to think of it as 'up' and 'down,' but rather as 'toward the pharynx.' In the lungs and the trachea, the movement is 'up' to move the mucus to the throat, and in the nasal cavity, the movement is 'down,' but again toward the throat. The aim is the movement of the mucus out of the respiratory tract and into the esophagus.

Comment: I knew that the returning is needed. The direction of the movement of particles that is caused by cilia is my question.

Comment: Where did this information come from? I'm wondering because there's not much detail and I don't know enough about the subject to know if it's reliable or not.

Answer (score -1):

The nasal cilia beat toward the rear of the nasal cavity, driving nasal mucus into the throat (pharynx). From there, it is mostly swallowed. Cilia never drive mucus out the front of the nose (nostrils).

Comment: Where did this information come from? I'm wondering because there's not much detail and I don't know enough about the subject to know if it's reliable or not.